# ¿Es posible realizar conexiones remotas a una base de datos alojada en MySQL utilizando una VPN?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ip, vpn, wifi

Tengo una base de datos alojada en MySQL Workbench y estoy buscando la forma de poder dar acceso a ella a otros computadores en otra ciudad. He probado realizar conexiones que me funcionan para dos PC´s conectados a la misma red de Wifi. Sin embargo, cuando no están en la misma red dicha conexión no me funciona. Ese es mi problema, ya que debo conectar la base de datos con computadores que están en otra ciudad y que trabajan para la misma empresa. Dicha empresa cuenta con una VPN. Entonces, mi duda es ¿Se puede usar la VPN (principalmente la IP que genera) para realizar la conexión de la base de datos que tengo con los servidores remotos? ¿Que configuraciones especificas debo hacer para que funcione?

Gracias.

Comment: Para conectar remotamente vía IP debes autorizar la IP. Si es fija, los riesgos de seguridad disminuyen, pero si es una IP dinámica, tendrás que autorizar a todas las IP, o a las IPs de un rango, en el caso de que las IPs remotas sigan siempre el mismo patrón. Quizá la forma más segura sería crear un túnel entre tu base de datos y esos equipos remotos. De este modo te conectarías de forma de segura y sin intercambiar contraseñas, porque este tipo de conexión utiliza llaves públicas / privadas. Revisa algún tutorial sobre crear túnel en MySQL en el sistema operativo en que estés trabajando.

Comment: Revisa el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-ssh.html) para más detalles. Y, una aclaración, esto no es correcto: *Tengo una base de datos alojada en MySQL Workbench*. Realmente `Workbench` no aloja ninguna base de datos, es simplemente una interfaz gráfica para interactuar con la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por responder. ¿Si utilizo el IP de la VPN para realizar la conexión remota funcionaría?